# Get selected column information in Kendo UI grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have one requirement for asp.net MVC application and for that inside Kendo UI grid, I have customized one column with combo box and two buttons for performing adding or deletion of any user selected value or manual typed value from combo box control.

But I am not able to get how I can get button click information for any specific row of that column.
Kindly guide how I can achieve such kind of behavior.

Sample Code for Grid is below and I want to get clickable for Category Column.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridHeaderTemplate.Models.ProductModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
            columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CategoryID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"], "CategoryID", "CategoryName")
                .Title("Category").HtmlAttributes(new
                {
                    @class = "templateCell"

                }).ClientTemplate("<table cellspacing='0' class='data-row data-personal'><tr>" +
                                        "<td>#=data.Category.CategoryName# <span class='custom-arrow k-icon k-i-arrow-s'></span></td>" +
                                        "<td><button id='customButton'>Add</button> <span></span> <button id='customButton1'>Delete</button></td>" +
                                        "</tr></table>")
                              .HeaderTemplate(
                            @<text>
                                <table cellspacing="0" class="data-header">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><strong>Category</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Category Name</td>
                                        <td>Settings</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </text>
                          )
                           .Width(300);//.ClientTemplate("#=data.Category.CategoryName# <span class='custom-arrow k-icon k-i-arrow-s'></span>"); ;
            columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Width(150);
            columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolBar =>
            {
                toolBar.Save();
                toolBar.Create();
            })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .Pageable()
            .Scrollable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
                model.Field(p => p.ProductID).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.CategoryID).DefaultValue(1);
            })
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code. Also include more detail explaining your issue.

Comment: Please edit your post to make it readable, separate code from regular text, it's all messed up

Answer (score 0):

Enter some code to help us helping you..

You need to have in your object the Id that you want to add or delete,

If you created a client template adding the two specific buttons and calling a javascript function, then you have acess to the properties of the row

for instance:

```
   column.Bound(c=>c.Id).hidden(true);
   column.Bound(c=>c.Name).ClientTemplate("<span onclick='AddToThisId(#=Id#)'>add</span>");
```

Edited:

CONTROLLER:

```
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
            {

        try
        {
           //Delete....

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.SetInsucess("Erro a apagar registo: " + ex.Message + ".");
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

VIEW

```
        <script>
         function AddSomethingBaseOnId(id){

         $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         type: 'GET',
         data: { Id: Id },
         contentType: "application/json",
         url: "Controller/AddAction",
         success: function (data) {
             alert("sucess");
         },
         fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
             alert("Ocorreu um erro: " + textStatus);
             $("#" + uid).hide();
         }
     });

       }

          function DeleteSomethingBaseOnId(id){

      $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         type: 'GET',
         data: { Id: Id },
         contentType: "application/json",
         url: "Controller/DeleteAction",
         success: function (data) {
             alert("sucess");
         },
         fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
             alert("Ocorreu um erro: " + textStatus);
             $("#" + uid).hide();
         }
     });

   }
  </script>
```

in your client template:

```
         "<td>#=data.Category.CategoryName# <span class='custom-arrow k-icon                      k-i-arrow-s'></span></td>" +
        "<td><button id='customButton'   onclick="AddSomethingBaseOnId(#=data.Id#)">Add</button> <span></span> <button  id='customButton1'    onclick="DeleteSomethingBaseOnId(#=data.Id#)">Delete</button></td>" +
```

Comment: I have added sample code..for my Grid View. Kindly tell me how i can get in such case.

Comment: i'm not sure if is that what you want.. but hope it helps.. anything let me know

Comment: Thanks a lot for update but i wanted to know that is there any other way to achieve this requirement. Kindly update me.

Comment: Hi sir_ask can you update me controller class method. how it would be there. Please suggest me best possible solution for above requirement and once again thanks a lot. As i was new web development it will help me a lot.

Comment: there is the action delete... you need to put in the right controller and change the Controller Name to the right one. The rest is logic, only you know what to do.     i dont understand exactly the logic that you are folowing. Cheers!

Comment: Requirement is 1. Allow for adds, deletes and updates of values for dropdown controls to be maintained in the Grid off application website.Provide a way to also sort the dropdown. These are 2 requirement i need to fulfill and for that i was thinking doing like this. So if you can suggest me what would be the best way to achieve this then it will help me a lot. Thanks once again.